# Пэйджинация, постраничный вывод. JpaRepository Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, mvc, jsp, jpa

Нужен постраничный вывод(pagenation). Использую spring MVC, в DAO интерфейс имплементирует JpaRepository.

```
public interface ThemeDao extends JpaRepository<Theme, Long> {
@Query
Page<Theme> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

@Service соответственно имеет метод:

```
 @Override
public Page<Theme> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return themeDao.findAll (pageable);
}
```

Что передать в @Controller?? Я должен передать, model.addAttribute лист с записями? тогда просто будет вывод всех записей..**Я не знаю что делать с конструктором.**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/forum"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String forum(Model model, Pageable pageable) {
    List<Theme> allInstanceTheme = themeService.findAll ();//это просто лист, не ограниченный ничем
    model.addAttribute ("allInstenceTheme", allInstanceTheme);//передали в JSP
    return "forum";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контроллер из [официальной документации](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/forum"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String forum(Model model, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Theme> themePage = themeService.findAll(pageable);
    model.addAttribute("themeList", themePage.getContent());
    return "forum";
}
```

А jsp-страница должна выглядеть обычно:

```
...
<ul>
  <c:forEach var="theme" items="${themeList}">
    <c:out value="${theme}" />
  </c:forEach>
</ul>
...
```

Comment: Я сделал так.

`Page allInstanceTheme = themeService.findAll (new PageRequest (page, 5));`

 Однако в JSP мой foreach не работает. 

А если сделать `List<Theme> themeList = themeService.findAll(pageable).getContext` тогда foreach просто выводит указанное в конструкторе themeService ограничение строк. А как сделать страницы я без малейшего понятия. Можете привести подробный пример конструктора и кода в jsp? Я был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно было передать pageable в конструктор метода, но тогда вылезала ошибка, что не получилось создать инстанс класса PageRequest. 
Я создал экземпляр класса, так все прекрасно работает.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/forum{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forum(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest (id, 5);
        Page allInstanceTheme = themeService.findAll (pageable);
        model.addAttribute ("allInstenceTheme", allInstanceTheme.getContent ());
        return "forum";
    }
```